# How can I make Find My Friends display distance in miles rather than km?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm in the UK, where (like the US) we use miles to measure distance, not kilometres. However, on both my iPhone and iPad the Find My Friends app in iOS 5 shows distances in km.

If I go to *Settings > General > International* and change my Region Format setting to United States, Find My Friends automatically switches to displaying distance in miles. Switch back to United Kingdom and frustratingly I'm back to km. Is there any other way to make Find My Friends pick up the correct unit for UK users?

Comment: Seams to me like a bug. What drawbacks are there if you just keep your region format set to US?

Comment: "Incorrect" display of dates for a start: in the UK we use DD MMM YYYY, not MMM DD, YYYY. All considered that wouldn't be a fix.

Comment: This is a silly bug, as we are a part of Europe our settings are defined as Europe, (good job we dont have an iSatNav we would be on the wrong side of the motorway) It is also confusing as in the UK we do use both KM and Miles, for example a runner will run 10KM or when swimming its done in KM. It is really driving where we use miles. So we should have the option to use which ever we need for what ever purpose, which is seen in Nike running app and in things like map my ride.

Comment: Just to note that this is fixed now, it displays in miles in the UK. This has been a problem for a while as Apple's Locale code thinks we use metric (and still does) only their newer MKDistanceFormatter realises that we use miles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The app doesn't currently have an override and simply takes the distance units from the system settings.

It surely would be nice to have finer control, but the code isn't there to make a change today.

Comment: That certainly seems to be the case, although the Maps app shows me distance in miles (and always has).

Answer (score 0):

Select 'friends' and 
tap on grey inverted horseshoe 'Me' at bottom and scroll to the bottom of the resulting screen and there you can select your distance preference.